# Button to show/hide multiple divs at once

Tags: jquery, css, html

I would like to have a single button that when clicked it shows multiple divs (3 or more) at once, and then when clicked again it hides the divs. I have found answers for showing multiple divs one at a time but i would like all the divs to pop up at the same time and hide at the same time from one button. The divs will be styled differently. Im sorry if this has already been answered and thank-you in advance for any answers

Comment: will you create buttons to control show/hide individual div? If not, .toggle() can help you easily. (existing answers are good) If yes, I would like to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you put a class say `hiddenDiv` on all the divs that need to made hidden and use

```
$('#hideButton').click(function() {
  $('.hiddenDiv').toggle();
});
```

Comment: @des: why that? why do all divs need to be inside of one div? Isn't a class itself enough even if they are in separate divs?

Answer (score 0):

Use this script:

```
$('#button-id').click(function(e) {
  $('#id1, #id2').toggle();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I would prefer `.toggle-div` instead of `#id-x` for easier maintenance.
Add `.toggle-div` in each div is good enough. 
e.g. `<div class="toggle_div div_style">`
Btw, .preventDefault() is good idea ;)

Comment: Yeah, I should've thought more about names, I guess I wanted to answer too fast. Anyways frictionlesspulley answer is better than mine, although he could use `preventDefault` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use ordinary javascript (if you don't like jQuery) and call twice (or more) function for hiding html elements.
Something like this:

```
<button onclick="divHideShow('divC');divHideShow('divD');">Click me</button>
```

Of course, divHideShow is function which hide div element. So call above hide divC and divD.
Find detailed instructions on: [Show or hide multiple divs](http://interestingwebs.blogspot.com//2011/05/show-or-hide-multiple-divs.html).